# New Swift array syntax and Generic function

Tags: arrays, xcode, generics, swift

Since Xcode beta 3, we can write `[int]` as short hand for `Array<Int>`.

So we should write this:

```
func commonElements <T, U where T: Sequence, U: Sequence,
    T.GeneratorType.Element: Equatable,
    T.GeneratorType.Element == U.GeneratorType.Element>
    (lhs: T, rhs: U) -> [T.GeneratorType.Element] {
        var result = [T.GeneratorType.Element]()
        for lhsItem in lhs {
            for rhsItem in rhs {
                if lhsItem == rhsItem {
                    result += rhsItem
                }
            }
        }
        return result
}
commonElements([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6])
```

For a reason I don't understand, Xcode doesn't accept the short syntax to initialize `result` array but accept its long equivalent `Array<T.GeneratorType.Element>()`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the compiler is getting confused.  This works though

```
var result: [T.GeneratorType.Element] = []
```

and is more readable IMO.

Comment: I think it's a compiler bug, the next Xcode beta may solve it. (NB: [Type]() is the syntax Apple uses in its Swift doc to declare empty array.)

Comment: @clmntcrl Apple uses both notations `[]()` appears 12 times in *The Swift Programming Language* and `[]` appears 7 times.